# ChoJSONWriter in append mode

Tags: c#, json, choetl

How do you open and write data into a file using ChoJSONWriter without overwriting existing data in the file?

This is what I've tried:

```
using (var parser = new ChoJSONWriter(fileName))
{
    parser.Write(data);
}
```

Comment: 'Append` maybe?

Comment: Perhaps you should try passing a stream (that was opened in append mode) to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can append JSON to existing file

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
{
    using (var parser = new ChoJSONWriter(sw))
    {
        parser.Write(data);
    }
}
```